# Reference Equality Python

Tags: list, object, mutable

I want to have a functionality like below. I have tried many things but still unable to achieve it.

```
>>> a, b = [1], [2]
>>> k = [a, a, b]
>>> k
[[1], [1], [2]]
```

Now as expected, if I change the second value the first value will be changed automatically.

```
>>> k[0][0] = 3
>>> k
[[3], [3], [2]]
```

You see how changing one value affects the other.

Now I want to somehow link the third element with the first two such that whenever I change any of the three elements, every element that it's linked to changes. I want to have the following behavior:

```
>>> *Do something to link k[1] or k[0] with k[2]*
>>> k[-1][0] = 4
>>> k
>>> [[4], [4], [4]]
```

I have tried doing the following and failed as you can see below:

```
>>> b = a
>>> k
>>> [[3], [3], [2]]
```

Please help me achieve the above.

**The real problem I want to solve:**
I am implementing min-cut algorithm. In this algorithm I need to merge two vertices at every step. I am trying doing this by linking the two vertices together which I want to merge.

Comment: Please could you clarify your question? Some of the examples you give don't work. For example, the first block (``a, b = [1], [1], [2]...``) would raise "``ValueError: too many values to unpack``". In the second block, you're assigning a ``str`` but the result you show is an ``int``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
a,b = [1],[2]
k = [a,a,b]  # store references to lists a and b
print(k)
k[0][0] = 3  # change the first cell's list's first element
print(k)     # second cell changes as well since it references same list
k[-1] = k[0] # store the first cell's reference in the last cell.  All reference the same list 'a' now.
k[1][0] = 4
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1], [2]]
[[3], [3], [2]]
[[4], [4], [4]]
```